# when do we say if two graphs are isomorphic and when do we say they are the same?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-isomorphism

A complete graph of 4 vertices can be represented with a square and also with a triangle with a vertex in the middle. I'm confused if I should call the two graphs isomorphic or the same?

Also, can all planar graphs be represented with straight non-intersecting edges in 2D?

Comment: I think you should say they are isomorphic, since isomorphism is a matter of structure, which means the way you represent the graph (as a triangle, a square,...) doesn't matter. A graph is only an ordered pair $(V,E)$, so that an isomorphism between $(V',E')$ is a bijection $V\to V'$ such that the edges are preserved.
The same graph would mean that $V=V'$ and $E=E'$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The definition of graph doesn't contain any indicators of shape. The drawing of a graph is only a graphical representation. These 2 graphs may be the same graph and be isomorphic (if they are the same set) or just be isomorphic. Isomorphic is a "safer" term, which should be used.

2) Yes, it is a theorem proven independently by K. Wagner (1936), I. Fáry (1948) and S. K. Stein (1951) and is known as Fáry theorem. Detailed proof may be found in G. Chartrand, L. Lesniak, *Graphs & Digraphs*, Wadsworth &Brooks/Cole, 1986 or newer edition (written with Ping Zhang).

Comment: Although interestingly, the *crossing number* of a graph (the minimum number of crossings it can be have in a representation in a plane) *can* be different depending on whether you restrict to straight edges.